# Use save() on one-to-one relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql

I have two models `User` and `Employee`. In the first one I have this function:

```
public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Employee','userid');
    }
```

And in the second one, there is this function:

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','userid');
    }
```

In my `employees` table, I have fields `firstname` and `lastname`. I'm just wondering if I could do the following somewhere in my code without any errors:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1); 
$user->employee->firstname = 'Joe';
$user->employee->lastname = 'Bloggs';
```

Now in order to save this update to the DB, which one of the two options do I use?

1: `$user->save();`

2: `$user->employee->save();`

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Yes, second one works with an output of `true` in Tinker. I was wondering if I could do it with the first way as well.

Comment: Again, have you tried it? If not, try it. If it works, it works. If not, it doesn't.